# Django (daphne, channels_redis) websocket disconnecting due to group_expiry after 24 hours

Tags: python, django, websocket, redis, daphne

I'm currently doing a django project where I need to be constantly connected to websockets. For the websockets I am using daphne server and channels_redis (with redis server). I'm having the problem that after 24 hours clients disconnect from the websockets due to group_expiry. Is there any way to set this group_expiry parameter of channels_redis to infinity, that would prevent the deletion of groups? Or is there some mechanism to restore the group (channel layers) connection? Thank you in advance for the answer

I tried setting the group_expiry parameter to -1, which for daphne meant infinity for websocket_timeout. Unfortunately, this doesn't help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.